# ArrayList null when using trying to pass through putExtra

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get an ArrayList of strings from another activity, and print out the elements like so:

```
ArrayList<String> foo;
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              //this does get called
    Intent extras = this.getIntent();
    foo = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("foo");

    for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)    //error, null object
        System.out.println(foo.get(i));
}
```

Instantiating it before getStringArrayListExtra doesn't help with the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
```

How else can I get the size of the ArrayList?

This is how I pass it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("foo",foo);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

I make sure it has data in it before passing

Comment: Is it in `onActivityResult()` then don't need to use `Intent extras = this.getIntent();` You will be received intent in `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data)
```

Use the intent received to `onActivityResult`, **NOT** `this.getIntent()`